# VSCode "Open Containing Folder" shortcut broke on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I am trying to use the "Open Containing Folder" keyboard shortcut for VSCode.

I am running VSCode 1.23.1, on Linux Mint 18.3.

I have confirmed the command works correctly when I use the mouse to initiate from the context menu.

But when I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> hotkey, it fails to work.

So either VSCode is broke or Linux Mint is eating that key combo.

I can not seem to confirm if the key combo is already assigned in Linux Mint. I have tried assigning that key combo to something else and it did not warn me that it is already mapped....so I assume it is not.

Comment: It works fine on 1.24.0

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the file or folder first, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> should work.

**If you're cursor is inside the text of the file, the shortcut will not work.**

You may need to upgrade to VSCode Version 1.24.0.

Comment: Is there anyone way to open it through short-cut while the cursor is in the file?

Comment: not the exact solution, but generally shift + F10 should open the right click menu.

Comment: You can have the file manager open even when the editor is focused by removing `!editorFocus` from the "When" field of the `revealFileInOS` shortcut. Code 1.54.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure US keyboard is first keyboard:

[image]